# Legend of Drizzt "Cavern Tile" triangle color

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

In the D&D Adventure game, The Legend of Drizzt, the cavern tiles have small triangles on them used to tell the players which edge of the tile will face the exploring hero.  These triangles are either black or white.  The rule book says the colors are "used to distinguish between less dangerous and more dangerous tiles."  I could not find any more information on what this really means.  I noticed they are often on tiles with volcanic vents and tiles with lots of exposed edges.  Are the colors just to tell me that tile is generally more dangerous due to exposure to surrounding tiles or volcanic explosions, or is there some specific rule(s) I am missing that pertains to their color?

Answer (score 6):

When you place a tile with a black triangle you are also supposed to draw an encounter card during the Villain phase, so tiles with black triangles definitely can be more dangerous than those with white triangles.

From page 6 of [the rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/LoD_Rulebook_EN.pdf) (right column, top of page):

> **Triangles:** Each tile features a triangle. When you place a new 
>   tile, the triangle points toward the unexplored edge of the tile 
>   it is attached to. If the tile has a black triangle, you draw an 
>   Encounter card during the Villain Phase of your turn.

And from page 8, Villain Phase, point 1:

> If you didn’t place a Cavern tile in your Exploration Phase, 
>   or if you placed a Cavern tile with a black triangle, draw 
>   and play an Encounter card.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: all tiles in the D&D adventure system have this rule and use black or white arrows. Wrath of Ashardalon has some Chamber entrances with maroon arrows; this is to signify that they signal a Chamber card instead of a regular encounter card.